# Residue of the function $ \frac{z^5 - iz^3}{\exp\left(\frac{1}{z-1}\right)-e} $ on $ z =1 $

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I'm trying to find the residue of the function :
$$ \frac{z^5-\mathrm iz^3}{\exp\left(\frac1{z-1}\right)-\mathrm e}$$
on the point $z=1$. In this point the function has essential singularity.

I either have to find the Laurent series of the function or try and calculate an integral of the function over a punctured circle, which I doubt it'll get me anywhere. I've tried calculating the Laurent series of the denominator, and I've got: 
$$\frac1{\exp\left(\frac1{z-1}\right)-\mathrm e}=\frac1{1-\mathrm e+\frac1{z-1}+\frac1{2(z-1)^2}+\cdots}  $$
However, I don't really think I'll progress much from this. I will gladly use some help to find out I'm missing something.

Comment: So you don’t need the full Laurent series (as implied by your title.)

Comment: you're right. I'm only looking for the residue, but I thought I might need to find the Laurent series, I've edited the title anyway

Comment: $z = 1$ is not an essential singularity. Consider the location of the poles of your function.

Comment: but I think it is an essential singularity because the limit at $ z = 1 $ does not exist. If we take $ z_n = 1 + \frac{1}{n} $, than we will get 
$ \frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^5 - i(1+\frac{1}{n})^3}{e^n - e} $ which tends to zero, however, if we take $z_n = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$, we get a limit which does not go to zero, I think to $\frac{1-i}{-e} $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may help you if I summarise the matter.

The denominator vanishes when

$$\frac{1}{z-1}=1+2kπi\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

so

$$z_k=1+\frac{1}{1+2kπi}$$

are all isolated singularities (simple poles) of $f(z)$.

Since

$$\lim_{k\to \infty} z_k=1$$

$z=1$ is a non-isolated singularity, as pointed out by Maxim in the comments. $f(z)$ cannot be expanded as a Laurent series around $z=1$ as every neighbourhood of $z=1$ contains other singularities, so the residue you asked about does not exist.

Comment: why refer to the asker in the third person?

Comment: I didn't really think it was disrespectful, just a bit formal perhaps, but I've corrected it now.

Comment: I'd just suggest you not treat users on this site in such ways.  Thanks for the edit.  Sometimes, formality is a way of behaving which implies a self-proclaimed superiority over others on this site.  Just be human.  That's all.

Comment: Ok, no problem. What, instead, I don't understand if the down vote refers to that formal issue or the substance of my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that $0$ is not at all an essential singularity from a friend.
Just because a function is not defined on a point, doesn't mean it has singularity there. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad you've got this point clear now.